# Query Builer for a Form checkbox Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to do a query builder to update my Form.

Here is how I want it to works :

I have Sessions linked to Etudes, those Etudes have Molecules and Bacteries.

So when I create a Session, in the create form, I want to have only lists of  Etude's Molecules and Etude's Bacteries.

This is my build Form for a Session :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')->add('dateCreation')->add('group')->add('etude')->add('antibiotique')
             ->add('molecules', \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class, ['class'=>'AppBundle:Molecule', 'choice_label'=>'nom', 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true, 'required'=>false])
            ->add('bacteries', \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class, ['class'=>'AppBundle:Bacterie', 'choice_label'=>'nom', 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true, 'required'=>false]);              
}
```

I've managed to preselect Bacteries whith a `foreach` like this but I don't like it very much, I've done it like this in my `controller` :

```
 $molecules = $etude->getMolecules();
    
    foreach($molecules as $molecule)
    {
     $session->addMolecule($molecule);
    }
```

Which give this, and in this example, I don't want it to show Mole 3, 4 and 5 :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeP5s.png)

Thanks a lot.